# How to make PUT request in Alamofire in swift 4

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am new to swift and Alamofire, I had a data from services that we are publishing in tableviews, but there is an option for the user to edit the data displaying in tableviews. Edited data should update the service and publish edited new data to the tableviews.

Data from service:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Sr",
        "designation": "",
        "officeLandLine": "456123789",
        "officeMobile": "789456",
        "officeEmail": "klm@mail.com",
        "personalEmail": "",
        "address": ""
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "S",
        "designation": "D",
        "officeLandLine": "0863",
        "officeMobile": "810",
        "officeEmail": "dy@gov.in",
        "personalEmail": "",
        "address": ""
    },
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this:

```
func serviceCallForUpdateData(withSelectedIndex index: Int){

    let param = ["id" : self.arry[index].id, "name" : self.arry[index].name]
        let requestURL = "your url"
            print("*****************************  URL: *********************************\(requestURL)")
            Alamofire.request(requestURL, method: .put, parameters: param as? Parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (responseJson) in
                print("Response : \(responseJson)")
                if (responseJson.result.isSuccess){
                    let dictRes = responseJson.result.value as! NSDictionary
                    completion(["res":dictRes, "stats":1] as AnyObject?)
                } else {
                    let res : NSDictionary = ["msg":"Network Error"]
                    completion(["res":res, "stats":0] as AnyObject?)
                }

            }
}
```

call this function in `didSelect` method of table view.

You can get the data from the array `didSelect` method.

In dedSelect method please write:

```
self.serviceCallForUpdateData(index : indexPath.row)
```

It may helps you.Thank you.

Comment: Hey @sanjukta thanks for your reply how can i add params for it and how to use those keywords "id" and "name" etc to save edit data

Comment: please see my update answer. Please consult me if arise any problem. Thank you